# Script no accepting commandline input? Positional Parameter help

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, io, parameter

Hello I am trying to create a simple file that reads in a filename and optionally the number of lines to output but I can't get my script to accept the positional parameter that I have assigned to hold the file name.

My Code:

```
#
#               task_4-1.sh filename [howmany] - optional parameter
#
#
#
# Read a file containing the names of and number of albums of artist in the album collection.
# Program will print the N highest lines of Artist with the highest Album count int he collection
# Default N is 10 
# One arguement for the name of the input file and a second optional line for how many lines to print.

#!\bin\bash

#Variable to accept the filename will print an error message if this value is left null 

filename=${1:?"missing."}

#Optional parameter that controls how many lines to Output to shell
howmany=${2:-10}

sort -nr $filename | head $howmany
```

When I try running the code on the commandline with:

```
task_4-1.sh albumnumber.txt 10
```

I get the error message head: 10 no such file or directory. 
If I switch assigning the parameter to this bracket syntax:

```
filename=${filename:?"missing."}
```

Then I get the error message I specified filename: "missing"

Don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing wrong is that you are missing the “-n” option in the last line. This works the way you expected.

```
sort -nr $filename | head -n $howmany
```

Comment: Thank you! Just realized this write when you responded haha.

Answer (score 0):

Same reason as [bashBedlam's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373815/165517)'s, but different code, (no `-n` option needed, this saves two bytes), just change this line:

```
 howmany=${2:-10}
```

To this:

```
 howmany=${2:--10}
```